# Rails CSS not working on a brand new project

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, react-on-rails

I'm pulling my hairs out here. I just created a `react on rails` app. No styling is working at all. This is a brand new project...

Solutions tried:

Precompiling in `assets.rb`

Linking stylesheet directing in the html.erb in the head

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>`

What am I missing here?

There is no track trace. The view renders fine just with no styling. No errors from the logs either.

Comment: You are missing your code samples and error stacktrace in this post :)

Comment: Make sure you have .css file exist in your repo for that controller.

Comment: No stacktrace. Page renders fine, It's just a normal HTML doc with zero styling

Comment: @GarrettJMU Don't Precompile your assets in development environment, otherwise it won't update changes in assets pipeline itself.